# Groupby with object and datetime64[ns] leas to empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
print(df.dtypes)
Daten                              float64
timepoint                   datetime64[ns]
Level                               object
Sublevel                            object
dtype: object
```

and the following entries:

```
Daten timepoint                 Level      Sublevel
1      2019-01-01T00:00:00.000   A          AA
1      2019-01-01T00:00:00.000   A          AA
2      2019-01-01T00:00:00.000   A          AB
2      2019-01-01T00:00:00.000   B          BA
1      2019-02-01T00:00:00.000   A          AA
```

I want to `groupby`and `sum` with the following command:

```
df= df.groupby(
        ['Level', 'timepoint']).agg({'Daten': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

why does this lead to an empty dataframe?

My expected output would be:

```
timepoint                 Level      Daten
2019-01-01T00:00:00.000   A          4
2019-01-01T00:00:00.000   B          2
2019-02-01T00:00:00.000   A          1
```

Comment: You example works fine for me. Can you provide a reproducible constructor? What are you python/pandas versions?

Comment: python 3.9.0 and pandas pandas 2.0.3

Comment: I added one more line to the example

Comment: can we have your complete code , as this seems to work as expected

Comment: Please provide **code** to set up the input DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this works:

```
df['timepoint'] = df['timepoint'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby(
     ['Level', 'timepoint']).agg({'Daten': 'sum'}).reset_index()
df['timepoint'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timepoint'])
```

Comment: It should (and was) also working with a timestamp. Did you have NaNs that were lost? In any case you shouldn't lose **all** your rows. Converting to string is not a good method.